# Need advice about hiding bootstrap divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a example of code that i need advice for:

```
<div class="container hidden-xs">
<div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="container hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <div class="row xtrastyle hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            Test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Assume i want one type of container and row for xs devices and one container and row for other devices. It doesnt work like this code. I need tips to use to get it work.

Comment: Split them up and wrap them in another "container"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the same contents with diffrent styling use css media queries.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row xtrastyle">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .xtrastyle {
        // apply your xtra style here
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Hint: If you use LESS instead of CSS you could use bootstrap @screen-sm variable instead of 768px: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less

Comment: Ok @sventschui add it for xs device and then xtrastyle has no effekt for other classes. Thats a way but i also want to know if its possible to work it out with something like i wrote in the question?

Comment: Since you're hiding the outer container on mobile devices and the inner container on any other devices there will never be something visible. So your approach will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Just put both containers on the same level in HTML like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
        Hidden XS
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container visible-xs">
    <div class="row">
        Visible XS
    </div>
</div>
```

See this working [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4iRaP9fVhw). Also, as you can see and @ganders pointed out in the comments, its easyly achievable using the `.visible-??` and `.hidden-??`-classes. (And much more readable btw.)
The corresponding bootstrap-classes are explained well in the [bootstrap-docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

Comment: would it also work (and be shorter) to do visible-xs and hidden-xs instead of specifying the hidden-sm, hidden-md, and hidden-lg?

Comment: yeah, i just did that in the meantime ;)

Comment: Yes thanks @nozzleman, this could be a way that i already know but if i have CMS content generated from a database i dont want to run this code two times like it should be with the suggestion.

Comment: If you are pulling it from a database then just use conditional statements to display one or the other

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't have this built in as that's a fairly niche use case. You'll have to write either some custom mixins (assuming you run into this issue often) or by modifying their behavior at various breakpoints.